# Sharepoint list with column type choice using radio button is always checked

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, list-view

I have sharepoint 2010 list with one column type as choice and is displayed using Radio Buttons with 4 options.

When we open the new item form the first value always selected by default.

What i need is , i dont want any of the option to be selected by default.

How to implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not set the default value for the column.

Answer (score 1):

In the list settings click on the column name to edit the column. At the bottom of the dialog is an option to set the default value. Delete any entries in there.

When a choice column is created, SharePoint will add the first item of the choices into that box. If you don't want any item to be selected by default, just leave that box blank.